# SwiftUI - View with condition

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm developing iOS App.
I'm curious how `if {} else {}` condition works with SwiftUI View's.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
   let condition: Bool

   var body: some View {
      if condition {
         ...
      } else {
         ...
      }
   }

}
```

I want to know does the code under negative condition is even generated but disabled by `if` condition? If so,  is it possible to build such View that generates only the code that meets certain condition? Sth with Lambda's?

I'm new to Swift, any examples would be helpful
Thanks!

Comment: I would say, since it is a closure, the whole code is compiled, but at runtime, when the closure is called to build the view, only the relevant branch of the `if` is executed (depending on `condition`).

Comment: @D.Mika The above code does not contain a closure or anything that will be compiled as a closure.

Comment: @idmean The part right behind the `View` is the closure.

Comment: @D.Mika No, this is a computed property not a closure. See [the `body` property in View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-swift.property?language=objc). A closure is a value that can be passed around. There is no way to take and pass around the function computing `body` so it is not a closure.

Comment: @idmean:  You're right. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI uses a [result builder](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md). Result builders allow you to transform every expression statement using a set of functions, i.e. they allow you to reduce all expression statements to one single value, which is then the result of the function.

However, this does not change the semantics of if-else apart from the logic that is necessary to carry over the transformed results and merge them into one value. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#selection-statements).

So, no, the block of if will be executed iff its condition evaluated to true and the else block iff the condition evaluated to false.

Comment: OK, I see. So even clousures won't help? I want to know should I worry that somewhere inside is "working" but hidden part of code. I would like to skip that due to obvious reasons like performance and others.

Comment: @MateuszKorga Help in what way? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I understood that in both cases the result will be generated but one of the parts on this 'html' will be hidden. Is it? Or only the true condition will be generated?

Comment: Only one part of the if is executed and the generated view is returned. There's nothing hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Although the views are shown conditionally, the types are still encoded. For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if true {
                Color.blue
            } else {
                Text("You'll never see me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is encoded as `Group<_ConditionalContent<Color, Text>>` even though the `Text` is never shown.

Such specific types make it easier for SwiftUI to diff Views - See the WWDC21 session "Demystifying SwiftUI" for a fuller explanation.